# Invoke c# event inside interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, default-interface-member

I am trying to invoke an event in the interface in which it is defined (see code below).
However, I get the following error:
`Program.cs(7,3): error CS0079: The event 'IMyInterface.MyEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`.
I suspect it might have something to do with all events declared in interfaces are always properties.
Is this a bug, a feature, and are there any workarounds?

Thanks.

```cs
using System;
public interface IMyInterface
{
    event EventHandler? MyEvent;
    void CallMyEvent()
    {
        MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public event EventHandler? MyEvent;
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new MyClass();
        obj.CallMyEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing that inside the interface anyway.

Comment: Why are you writing implementation code in your interface? I know it's a new feature of c#, but, why?

Comment: It looks like you're right about the event in the interface only being the add/remove api without a backing field https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2928

Comment: Make `CallMyEvent` a regular interface defined method. Create an abstract implementing IMyInterface. Put the `CallMyEvent` impl in there. Change to `MyClass : MyAbstract`.

Comment: You can only do inside a default implementation what an external consumer of the interface can do (which is after all the position the default implementation is in w.r.t. any actual implementation)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because `event EventHandler? MyEvent` not implemented inside your interface, it will be implemented inside your class and after it, you can `Invoke` it:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public event EventHandler? MyEvent;

    public void CallMyEvent()
    {
        MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

After C# 8 you actualy can do default implementation of methods inside `interface`, but only methods, not events.

If you want predefined method, that will call event, you can make `abstract class` instead of `interface`.

Comment: I guess the question was how to invoke it in the interface. (Hint: for multi inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the only way around this problem is to invoke the event outside the interface. Either use an abstract class that I was trying to avoid, or have a regular interface method and give up DRY code.